# Send xls file Telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

i'm trying to send a xls file. Looking online and after 2 hours, I didn't figure out where is it the error.
I'm trying to send this file from an url. Here's my code

```
$filePath = $dburl."Last_season.xls";
$document = new CURLFile($filePath);
$post = array('chat_id' => $callback_id_username,'document'=> $document,'caption' => $caption);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$GLOBALS[website]."/sendDocument");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result_curl = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending xls files via url is currently not supported.

> **Sending by URL** - In sendDocument, sending by URL will currently only work for **gif**, **pdf** and **zip** files.

See Bot API [sending files](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files).

To work around this issue you can first store the xls file on your system and use this file - instead of the url.

One way to do this:

```
$url_of_file = $dburl."Last_season.xls";
$file_name = basename($url_of_file);
file_put_contents( $file_name,file_get_contents($file_name)); //store xls file named "Last_season.xls" locally
$document = new CURLFile($file_name);
$post_data = ["chat_id" => ADMIN_CHAT_ID, "document" => $document];
```